# Spire.DOC NullReference when adding row to table

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception, doc, spire

I'm generating pdf with Spire.Doc (https://ibb.co/6sW9cjk).
In different sub that code works nicely, but when copied to another sub (will provide the same functionallity as original one) code breaks.

Simple:

1. get first row of table
2. fill cells with data
3. insert new row
4. repeat unit there is data

Everything is initialized properly, `doc` is using existing doc file as template to fill it with data.

Today I noticed that even original code is not working! Same error, `NullReferenceException` when adding second row to table.

If I do like this:

```
dri.Cells(0).AddParagraph()
dri.Cells(0).FirstParagraph.Text = itemsInReceiptCount
```

Code works but data is not in table row but under the table. (https://ibb.co/y06nnpP)

Is there any cool fix? Everything was working fine until (???).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

Somehow code like I mentioned in question doesnt work, but (!) if I did it like that:

```
For Each i As TableCell In dri.Cells
   i.AddParagraph()
Next
```

Code will work, table will generate properly (but without borders - easily fixable), paragraphs can be filled with data, no exceptions or errors.

So, I think if it works, it will stay like this.